# How to display a video in one layer and camera view in another layer in same window

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing, qt4

I need to design a GUI in such a way that a video should be played in one thread (as a panel in the frame or window) and Camera video should be captured and displayed in another thread(as a panel in the frame or window). Please find the below link for the

I need a GUI as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA883X4uaHk (pl watch from .35s).

I found that this can be done in QT. But am bit new to QT. Can Some one give me some tips on how to do this in QT.? Anything with the basic code to handle frames and panels would be really helpful.

Comment: Do the libraries you plan on using support rendering to an offscreen frame buffer?

Comment: For example, you can use OpenGL: just add N opengl widgets to your GUI and show in them everything you want. To show video in opengl you need to draw rectangle and use dynamic texture — frames of your video.